# Puppet manifest to download java by passing cookies and no certificate

Tags: puppet

I am trying to prepare manifests to download java using Puppet. This is my manifest

```
class java {
 $install_path ="/opt/softwares"
 $user_home="/home/vidyayug"



  exec { "download_java":
    command => "wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u4-b20/jdk-7u4-linux-x64.tar.gz" ",

    cwd  => "$user_home/archives",
    path => [ "/usr/bin", "/bin"],
    require => Package["wget"],
    creates => "$user_home/archives/jdk-7u4-linux-x64.tar.gz",
    timeout => 60000000
}



  exec { "untar_jdk" :
    command => "tar -xvzf $user_home/archives/jdk-7u4-linux-x64.tar.gz",
    cwd =>"$install_path",
    path => ["/usr/bin","/bin"],
    require => [Package["tar"],],
    unless => "test -d ${$install_path}/jdk*"

}

}
```

When i run Puppet, i am having the following issue :

```
 vidyayug@liferay:~/puppet/manifests$ sudo puppet apply site.pp --modulepath=../modules/
Warning: The use of 'import' is deprecated at /home/vidyayug/puppet/manifests/site.pp:9. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/puppet-import-deprecation
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/parser/parser_support.rb:110:in `import')
Error: Syntax error at 'Cookie'; expected '}' at /home/vidyayug/puppet/modules/java/manifests/init.pp:16 on node liferay
Error: Syntax error at 'Cookie'; expected '}' at /home/vidyayug/puppet/modules/java/manifests/init.pp:16 on node liferay
vidyayug@liferay:~/puppet/manifests$
```

The command to download java is working as expected on the command line but not with Puppet. Previously i was able to install java through apt-get using Puppet.

Please help me to resolve the above issue as i need to install a specific version of JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting double quotes, so puppet thinks your command string ends just before "Cookie". You either need to escape the double quotes inside the string or replace the outermost double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: Hi Chris Pitman after adding singles quotes in the manifest, JAVA was downloaded. Thanks for your help.